# I want to change visible button when array change on Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I want to toggle visible button when array changed. But I can't do it.What is the best way to do this?

Here is my example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-poincare-vv6xh?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Answer (score 0):

You try updating toggleUser function like below:

```
toggleUser(value) {
  this.$set(this.markedUserArr, this.index, value);
}
```

Check [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) for more details